# Retrieving Image with original resolution

Tags: android

I am retrieving an image(as a Bitmap) from res/drawable folder and displaying it using a custom view by overriding onDraw method. The actual resolution of the image is 400*400. But when I measured the Bitmap size after retrieving it from res/drawable, I found the image size to be 200*200. I actually want to retain the original Image resolution. How can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading an image using the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html), you can pass an [Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) object.

Set the field **inScaled** of your Options object to false and the bitmap will load with no scaling.